# Check list of Package names for valid names

Tags: debian, apt

I have a relatively grown bash install script I use to install my standard software on fresh debian installations. It mainly consists of `apt-get install -f -y` lines. I started it in Debain 8 and recently while setting up a Debian 9 i noticed some package names have changed. Is there an efficient way to check all these packages if the package name in my script is still valid or the name has changed? Or do I have to check them all manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the return code of `apt-cache show` (assuming you have performed `apt update` first).

```
$ apt-cache show curl > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
0
$ apt-cache show foo > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
100
```

Comment: Great thanks!
Can you explain what the part after `show curl >` does? Or at least say how this technique is called so I can read about?

Comment: It is redirecting the command output to /dev/null (the digital black hole). I use 2>&1 because this redirects stderr into stdout. Both of these pipes now write to 'nothing', so you get no output. The semicolon is just a delimiter for the next command. $? is a special variable that stores the return code of the last executed program.

Comment: that's super useful as it works for other commands too (just tried with `dpkg-query -s`). way better than grepping verbose outputs

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Debian 9 and it has the packages you want, you can dump them using `dpkg` and ignore your list entirely,

```
dpkg --get-selections > packages.txt
```

You can then restore the system to the exact configuration with,

```
dpkg --set-selections - < packages.txt
apt-get dselect-upgrade
```